# How to transport property to slot in vue in jsx?

Tags: vue.js, jsx

```html
//vue SFC
<div>
  <slot myProp="myProp"></slot>
</div>
```

```html
//vue jsx
<div>
  {this.$slots.default}//myProp???
</div>
```

I'm using vue with jsx. How to transport `myProp` to `this.$slots.default` in vue in jsx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`vm.$scopedSlots`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-scopedSlots) contains a map of slot names to render functions, which can receive slot props.

To pass `myProp` as a slot prop to the default slot:

```html
<div>{this.$scopedSlots.default?.({ myProp: "hello world" })}</div>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/passing-slot-props-in-jsx-266ic?file=/src/components/MyComponent.vue:39-119)